# Ruby one-line failing because of directory

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a ruby one-liner `ruby1.9 -ine '#some statement' src/**`. I assumed, like perl does, ruby skips the directories ( well that's how I remember it ). But I get this error `e:1:in 'gets': Is a directory`. Besides giving it a list of files, is there a quick way of getting round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only files recursively, then **find(1)** will be your best bet :

```
find ./src -type f | ruby1.9 -ne '#some statement'
```

Comment: Sadly `find` doesn't pipe the files it finds ( well it doesn't on my system ). It just prints them

Comment: You'd like to display files content, right ? So add -exec cat :                          find ./src -type f -exec cat {} \; | ruby1.9 -ne '#some statement'

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I had taken `-i` out. But now I get this `ruby1.9: No such file or directory -- (LoadError)
` Ugh...

Comment: And making `-i` alone - instead of `-ine` it's `-i -ne` - I get this `-e:1: warning: Can't do inplace edit for stdio`. I get the feeling I can't pipe

Comment: In the end I just did a proper file list so `src/*` and then, `src/*/*` and so on. Without piping ( since piping didn't work for me ) just the plain ruby command

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it ever skipped directories, at least even 1.8.6 does not. So I suppose the only quick way is to give it a list of files, or to manipulate ARGV, but it'd hardly be a proper one-liner then anymore.

Something like this:

```
ruby -ne 'ARGV.delete_if{|s| File.ftype(s) == "directory"}; do_stuff_here' src/**
```

So yeah, giving it a proper file list seems to be the nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your assumption is actually about your *shell's* handling of `**`. The shell interprets un-escaped meta-characters in commands.

`bash(1)` by default will not expand `**` recursively. You need to set the `globstar` option for this behavior:

```
$ ls -l /tmp
total 20
drwx------ 2 sarnold sarnold 4096 2011-11-17 15:43 keyring-9mdW7p
drwx------ 2 gdm     gdm     4096 2011-11-17 15:43 orbit-gdm
drwx------ 2 sarnold sarnold 4096 2011-11-17 15:44 orbit-sarnold
drwx------ 2 sarnold sarnold 4096 2011-11-17 15:46 plugtmp
drwx------ 2 sarnold sarnold 4096 2011-11-17 15:43 ssh-ZriaCoWL2248
$ shopt -u globstar
$ echo /tmp/**
/tmp/keyring-9mdW7p /tmp/orbit-gdm /tmp/orbit-sarnold /tmp/plugtmp /tmp/ssh-ZriaCoWL2248
$ shopt -s globstar
$ echo /tmp/**
/tmp/ /tmp/keyring-9mdW7p /tmp/keyring-9mdW7p/control /tmp/orbit-gdm /tmp/orbit-sarnold /tmp/orbit-sarnold/linc-9a5-0-240e051029b41 /tmp/orbit-sarnold/linc-9ad-0-1b1412421b16c /tmp/plugtmp /tmp/ssh-ZriaCoWL2248 /tmp/ssh-ZriaCoWL2248/agent.2248
```

Comment: .. though my answer retains the directories in the output. Hrm.